# Building own API

Tags: asp.net, security, architecture

I'm working on a project (in ASP.NET) and will soon have to start implementing own API for users to allow them using the functionality from their code. I have done some research (e.g. found nice article here: http://www.startupcto.com/backend-tech/building-an-api-best-practices) in order to follow the best practice and I'm pretty much decided for RESTful service and JSON as a return format.

My question - would you have any tips from your personal experience or any advice what to be careful about or possibly some good sources/articles on this topic?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Web API 2 could be a good candidate, if you do not need WCF's advanced features. [WCF and ASP.NET Web API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Some great blog series (11 or 13 parts) here:

http://bitoftech.net/2013/11/25/building-database-model-entityframework-code-first

and some newer ones:

http://bitoftech.net/tag/web-api-2/

Lots of official sample projects here:

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Also if you have a pluralsight subscription or use their trial there are lots of good (and mostly recent) videos to help you out.

http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/implementing-restful-aspdotnet-web-api

http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/html5-line-of-business-applications

and others